# finding the magnitude of an complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $u=6e^\frac{4\pi i}{7}$ and $v=11e^\frac{9\pi i}{5}$. Find $|u+v|$.

So $|u+v|=|6e^\frac{4\pi i}{7}+11e^\frac{9\pi i}{5}|$

I know that $|x|$ is equal to sqrt of the conjuate of x times x but how do I find the conjugate of $u+v$?

Comment: Conjugation is linear (distributes over addition) and also transfers into the exponent. You pretty much just replace $i$ by $-i$ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to rectangular form $r e^{i\theta}=cos\theta+i sin(\theta)$ before adding.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Any complex number $z = re^{i\theta}$ can be defined as a vector with its tail at the origin, length $r$ and makes an angle $\theta$ with the positive real line.

We can then apply the rules of vector addition to find $|u+v|$. Here the vector $u+v$ is the diagonal of the parallelogram formed by the vectors $u$ and $v$. An example diagram can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Addition_and_subtraction).

Using the cosine law:

$$|u+v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2 + 2|u||v|\cos \Delta\theta$$

$\Delta\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$, in this case is $\frac{9\pi}{5} - \frac{4\pi}{7} = \frac{43\pi}{35}$